# PowerShell WMI shows the same value

Tags: powershell

I actually have two questions I'm hoping someone can help me with.

The purpose of this script is to give me visibility if machines are running on high memory and CPU consumption. The list of servers is defined in a txt file called ServerList1.txt. The results are dumped to an HTML file.

1. Please see the code below. When you set your CPU to a value over 70%, the script should display which machine is over the 70% mark. Currently, if I set a machine to 100% CPU, it shows 100$ for ALL machines listed. Any idea as to why? I've been scratching my head at it for some time now.
2. Related to the above, when a machine hits a value higher than 70%, the table cell should fill with red. right now, it will fill in all the cells with red. I'm guessing once I can figure out why it shows 100% for all the machines, this issue should also correct itself and only highlight the cell as red for a particular machine.

Below is the code: (Yes, it's a little sloppy I'm just trying to get things working for now.)

```
            $ServerListFile = "C:\Monitor\ServerList1.txt"
            $ServerList = Get-Content $ServerListFile -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            $GetDate = (Get-Date).ToString("dddd MMMM dd - hh:mm:ss tt")    
            $Result = @() 

            ForEach ($ComputerName in $ServerList)
            {   
            ### Processor %
            $Proc = Get-counter -Counter "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" -SampleInterval 1
            $CPU = ($Proc.Readings -split ":")[-1]
            $CPU = [math]::Round($CPU,2)
            ### Memory %
            $Memory = Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Computername $ComputerName | Select-Object @{Name = "MemoryUsage"; Expression = {"{0:N2}" -f ((($_.TotalVisibleMemorySize - $_.FreePhysicalMemory)*100)/ $_.TotalVisibleMemorySize)}}
            $Memory = $Memory | Select-Object -ExpandProperty MemoryUsage
            ### Create custom objects for report
            $Result += [PSCustomObject] @{
            ServerName = "$ComputerName"
            CPULoad = "$($CPU)%"
            Memory = "$($Memory)%"
            }

            ### HTML formatting 
            $Report = "
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
                <head>
                    <meta http-equiv=""refresh"" content=""1; URL=Test.htm"" />
                    <link rel=""shortcut icon"" href=""favicon.png"" type=""image/x-icon"" />
                    <title> Server Health Report</title>
                    <style>

                        html, body {
                            height: 100%;
                            background-color: #e6e6e6;
                        }
                        html {
                            display: table;
                            margin: auto;
                        }

                        body {
                            display: table-cell;
                            vertical-align: top;
                        }
                        p {
                            font-family: Microsoft Tai le;
                        }
                        h1 {
                            color: rgb(153,0,0);
                            text-align: center;
                            font-family: Microsoft Tai le;
                            font-size: 50px;
                        }
                        h2 {
                            color: rgb(153,0,0);
                            text-align: center;
                            font-family: Microsoft Tai le;
                            font-size: 30px;
                        }
                        td {
                            font-family: Microsoft Tai le;
                            font-size:24px;
                            padding:8px 12px;
                            border-style:solid;
                            border-width:1px;
                            /*overflow:hidden;*/
                            word-break:normal;
                            border-color:#999;
                            color:#444;
                            border-top-width:1px;
                            border-bottom-width:1px;
                        }
                    </style>
                </head>
                <body>
                <h1>Server Health Report</h1>
                <h2>$GetDate</h2>
                <table border=1 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0> 
                    <tr bgcolor=#00ace6 align=center> 
                    <td><b>Server Name</b></td> 
                    <td><b>CPU Utilization</b></td>
                    <td><b>Memory Utilization</b></td>
                </tr>"

                Foreach($Entry in $Result)
                    { 
                        IF ($CPU -gt "70" -or $Memory -gt "70")
                            {                           
                                #$Report += "<tr bgcolor=#ff0000>"
                                $Report += "<trfont-color=#ff0000></font>"
                                $ReportDate = Get-Date -format "dddd MMMM dd - hh:mm:ss tt"                         
                                $ReportName = $Entry.Servername                         
                                $ReportCPU = $Entry.CPULoad                         
                                <#Write-Output "========== LOG ENTRY ==========" | Out-File C:\Monitor\Testmonitor.txt -Append                          
                                Write-Output "Timestamp: $ReportDate " | Out-File C:\Monitor\Testmonitor.txt -Append                            
                                Write-Output "Server Name: $ReportName" | Out-File C:\Monitor\Testmonitor.txt -Append                           
                                Write-Output "CPU Utilization: $ReportCPU" | Out-File C:\Monitor\Testmonitor.txt -Append                            
                                Write-Output "" | Out-File C:\Monitor\Testmonitor.txt -Append                           
                                Write-Output "" | Out-File C:\Monitor\Testmonitor.txt -Append#>                 
                            }                       
                        ELSE
                            { 
                                $Report += "<tr>"
                            }
                        $Report += "<td align=center>$($Entry.Servername)</td>
                                    <td align=center>$($Entry.CPULoad)</td>
                                    <td align=center>$($Entry.Memory)</td>
                                    </tr>"  
                    } 
            $Report += "</table></body></html>"  
            }  

            $Report | Out-File C:\Monitor\Test.htm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line, just inside the `Foreach($Entry in $Result)` loop

```
IF ($CPU -gt "70" -or $Memory -gt "70")
```

This is using the temporary variables leftover from the previous loop, which contain data for just the last object in the `$Result` array.  The line you want is:

```
IF ($Entry.CPU -gt "70" -or $Entry.Memory -gt "70")
```

Comment: Thank you @ryan-bemrose, I just noticed that as well when reviewing the code but it still does the same thing when switching. I changed it to `IF ($Entry.CPULoad -gt "70%" -or $Entry.Memory -gt "70%")` to match my code. Any ideas why it still shows all machines at 100% CPU? I'll take another crack at this.

Comment: D'oh! Found the problem. I was setting the following variable: `$Proc = Get-counter -Counter "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" -SampleInterval 1` which was not asking to get the results from a machine. Adding `$Proc = Get-counter -Computer $ComputerName-Counter "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" -SampleInterval 1` now works!